# Regular Expression for starting woth specfic number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to write regular expression for following conditions:

1. Should have only numbers
2. Must be 8 digits long
3. Must start with 8 or 9 or 6

So for I can do only for first two conditions. I am not sure how to do the third conditions
My code is

```
 if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $number))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Simply remove the first number from the character class and validate it at the start of your pattern...

```
/^(8|9|6)\d{7}$/
```

FYI - `\d` is the escape sequence for *digits*. I suppose you could also use this

```
/^[896]\d{7}$/
```

as it means about the same thing when you're only watching for a single character at the start.